# Extending product API response?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

When loading a product's data in the API via *https://example.org/index.php/rest/default/V1/products/:sku*, I need to make some changes to the returned data. For example, I'd like to rename the existing "id" field to "entity_id". I would also add some additional fields that are not based on product attributes.

I am wondering what my best strategy would be for this? I realize I could just create my own API route and have that return all the product data that I want, and changing the names of the fields accordingly. However, I am wondering if there would be a good strategy to extend the current response from *https://example.org/index.php/rest/default/V1/products/:sku* so that I can have my additional/changed data returned from that route?

Comment: You should use extension_attrbiutes for product interface. I think that's the best strategy to customize API responses.

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi: I totally agree, but some APIs that we're working with require an exact format of API responses. For example, I *have* to include the product ID labeled as "entity_id" as a direct "child" of the main response. It can not be a child of the "extension_attributes" (or similar) node.